# Two questions on Munkres -Topology: product and subspace of separable spaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, product-space, separable-spaces

I  have **two** questions:

- If $X$ is a countable product of spaces having countable dense subsets then does $X$ have a countable dense subset?

Let $X$ $=\prod_{i=1}^\infty  X_i$. Let $D_i$ denote the countable dense subset of the space $X_i$. Then $\scr D$ $=\prod_{i=1}^\infty D_i$ is a countable set as Cartesian product of countable sets is countable. Secondly $\overline {\prod _{i=1}^\infty D_i}=\prod _{i=1}^\infty \overline {D_i}=X$. Hence $\scr D$ is the required set. Is this correct?

- Is a subspace of a separable topological space separable?

$\Bbb R$ has  $\Bbb Q$ as countable dense set, but $\Bbb Q^c$ does not have a countable dense subset. How should I prove this fact? Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your arguments are wrong, I’m afraid. The Cartesian product of countably infinitely many countably infinite sets is uncountable, so $\prod_kD_k$ is not in general a countable subset of $X$, though it is a dense subset. It is nonetheless true that $X$ is separable. For each $k\in\Bbb N$ fix a point $p_k\in D_k$, and let

$$D=\left\{\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in\prod_kD_k:\exists m\in\Bbb N\,\forall k\ge m(x_k=p_k)\right\}\;;$$

now show that this set $D$ is both countable and dense in $X$.

For the second question, $\Bbb R$ has a countable base, so every subspace of $\Bbb R$ has a countable base and therefore a countable dense subset. In particular, $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is separable. (A specific example of a countable dense subset of the irrationals is $\{q+\sqrt2:q\in\Bbb Q\}$.

It is true, however, that a subset of a separable space need not be separable. In fact, you can build an example by changing the topology of $\Bbb R$. Let each $x\in\Bbb Q$ be isolated. For $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ and $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $B_n(x)=\left(x-\frac1n,x+\frac1n\right)$, and let $\{B_n(x):n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ be a local base at $x$.

- Verify that this yields a topology on $\Bbb R$.
- Show that $\Bbb R$ is separable in this topology.
- Show that $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is *not* separable in this topology.

Comment: Sir two questions 1. I am really not getting how $D$ has been constructed or how does it's elements look like ;Is it possible to elaborate a bit  2.For specifying a topology on a set we need to give the collection of open sets  but you did not do that .Can you please do that ?I am not getting the concept of **local base** here.

Comment: @learnmore: Let $p=\langle p_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$; this is a point in $\prod_kD_k$. $D$ consists of all of the points in $\prod_kD_k$ that differ from $p$ on at most finitely many coordinates. If each $X_k$ were $\Bbb R$, for instance, each $D_k$ were $\Bbb Q$, and each $p_k=0$, $D$ would be the set of rational sequences with only finitely many non-zero coordinates. \\ A local base at a point is also called a *neighborhood base* at the point; you may know it under this name. It’s a fundamental concept that I’d expect to find in any topology text. At any rate, what I’ve defined *is* a ...

Comment: ... genuine system of local bases, and it generates a topology $\tau$ in the following way: a set $U\subseteq\Bbb R$ is in $\tau$ if and only if for each $x\in U$ there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}_x$ such that $B\subseteq U$, where $\mathscr{B}_x=\{B_n(x):n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ if $x$ is irrational, and $\mathscr{B}_x=\big\{\{x\}\big\}$ if $x$ is rational.

Comment: My attempt: As constructed $D$ becomes the finite product of countably many dense sets and hence countable. Take any basic open set may be $\scr U=$ $ U_1\times U_2\times... \times U_n\times X\times ...X$ Now as each $U_i$ intersects $D_i$ we have $x_i\in U_i\cap D_i$ for all $1\le i\le n$ then $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,p,p...,p)\in \scr U\cap D$

Comment: Is the arguement correct?

Comment: @learnmore: You have the right general idea, but it needs some work. First, $D$ is not the product of finitely many sets. It is, however, the union of countably many countable sets. For each $n$ let $$D(n)=\{x\in D:x_k=p_k\text{ for all }k>m\}\;.$$ Then $D=\bigcup_nD(n)$, and for each $n$ there is a bijection between $D(n)$ and $\prod_{k\le n}D_k$, which is countable, because it’s the product of *finitely* many countable sets. Your argument for $D$ being dense in $X$, however, is correct.

Comment: @learnmore: You’re very welcome.